# Send-MailMessage not sending if $body updated in catch

Tags: powershell

If the script runs without any errors related to the `ForEach-Object` loop, a message is generated as expected.  If the `catch` occurs however, `` $body += "$intelError `r`n`r`n" `` seems to be hitting some sort of character limit or creating an error silently.

Lastly, I'm getting "too many recipients" from office365.  Anyone know of a way around this without using a distribution list?

```
$clientID = "Blargh Inc"
$intelDir = "C:\Threat Intelligence"
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$intelSource = "$($intelDir)\sources.csv"

# Begin Email Options
$body = "Threat Intelligence Feed ran for $clientID - Errors listed below (if applicable) `r`n`r`n"
$email = @{
From = "me@mycompany.com"
To = "me@mycompany.com","notme@mycompany.com"
Subject = "$($clientID) - Threat Intelligence - Summary"
SMTPServer = "mail-server.office365.com"
Body = $body
}
# End Email Options

import-Csv $intelSource | ForEach-Object {
    $storageDir = "$($intelDir)\$($_.threatType) $($_.threatSubtype)"
    $threat = $_.threatType + "_" + $_.threatSubtype    # Set this variable to save headaches passing it later
    $storageFile = "$($storageDir)\$($threat)_$($(get-date -f MM-dd-yy)).csv"    # Filename specified by sources.csv fields and today's date
    $url = $_.threatLocation
    # Begin Error Handling
    try {
        $webclient.DownloadFile($url,$storageFile)
    }
    catch {
        $intelError = $_.Exception|format-list -force
        $body += "$intelError `r`n`r`n"
        echo $intelError | Out-File $intelDir\$threat"_ErrorLog_"$(get-date -f MM-dd-yy).txt -Append
        Continue
    }
    # End Error Handling
    # Cleanup
    finally {
        $webclient.Dispose()
    }
    # Throttling (mainly future use with multiple sources)
    Start-Sleep 5
    }
Send-MailMessage @email
```

## Updated Code - Errors not continuing past Try-Catch

```
$clientID = "Blargh Inc"
$intelDir = "C:\Threat Intelligence"
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$intelSource = "$($intelDir)\sources.csv"
$intelCount = 0
$intelError = 0

# Begin Email Options
$body = "Threat Intelligence Feed ran for $clientID - "
$subject = "$($clientID) - Threat Intelligence - "
$email = @{
From = "me@mycompany.com"
To = "me@mycompany.com","notme@mycompany.com"
Subject = $subject
SMTPServer = "mail-server.office365.com"
Body = $body
}
# End Email Options

import-Csv $intelSource -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ForEach-Object {
        $storageDir = "$($intelDir)\$($_.threatType) $($_.threatSubtype)"
        $threat = $_.threatType + "_" + $_.threatSubtype    # Set this variable to save headaches passing it later
        $storageFile = "$($storageDir)\$($threat)_$($(get-date -f MM-dd-yy)).csv"    # Filename specified by sources.csv fields and today's date
        $url = $_.threatLocation
        # Begin Error Logging
        try {
            $intelCount++
            $webclient.DownloadFile($url,$storageFile)
        }
        catch {
            $intelError++
            $intelErrorMessage = $_.Exception|format-list -force
            echo $intelErrorMessage | Out-File $intelDir\$threat"_ErrorLog_"$(get-date -f MM-dd-yy).txt -Append
            Continue
        }
        # End Error Logging
        # Cleanup
        finally {
            $webclient.Dispose()
        }
        # Throttling (mainly future use with multiple sources)
        Start-Sleep 5
        }
if ($intelError -gt 0) {
    $email.Item('Subject') += "$($intelError) Error(s)"
    $email.Item('Body') += "$($intelError) of $($intelCount) sources failed. See attached error log(s)"
    Get-ChildItem -Path $intelDir | Where {$_.Name -match "$($(get-date -f MM-dd-yy))"} | foreach{$_.fullname} | Send-MailMessage @email
}
else {
    $email.Item('Subject') += "Success"
    $email.Item('Body') += "No errors"
    Send-MailMessage @email
}
```

This is the error that occurs if a source fails (and consequently, the conditions which occur if an e-mail does NOT get sent).

```
ErrorRecord                 : Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request."
StackTrace                  :    at System.Management.Automation.DotNetAdapter.AuxiliaryMethodInvoke(Object target, Object[] arguments, MethodInformation methodInformation, Object[] originalArguments)
                             at System.Management.Automation.ParserOps.CallMethod(Token token, Object target, String methodName, Object[] paramArray, Boolean callStatic, Object valueToSet)
                             at System.Management.Automation.MethodCallNode.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Object value)
                             at System.Management.Automation.MethodCallNode.Execute(Array input, Pipe outputPipe, ExecutionContext context)
                             at System.Management.Automation.ParseTreeNode.Execute(Array input, Pipe outputPipe, ArrayList& resultList, ExecutionContext context)
                             at System.Management.Automation.StatementListNode.ExecuteStatement(ParseTreeNode statement, Array input, Pipe outputPipe, ArrayList& resultList, ExecutionContext context)
WasThrownFromThrowStatement : False
Message                     : Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request."
Data                        : {}
InnerException              : System.Net.WebException: An exception occurred during a WebClient request. ---> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Threat Intelligence\zeus test\zeus_test_11-12-15.csv'.
                             at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
                             at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromPr
                          oxy)
                             at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
                             at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
                             at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
                             --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
                             at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
                             at DownloadFile(Object , Object[] )
                             at System.Management.Automation.DotNetAdapter.AuxiliaryMethodInvoke(Object target, Object[] arguments, MethodInformation methodInformation, Object[] originalArguments)
TargetSite                  : Void     ExecuteStatement(System.Management.Automation.ParseTreeNode, System.Array,     System.Management.Automation.Internal.Pipe, System.Collections.ArrayList ByRef,     System.Management.Automation.ExecutionContext)
HelpLink                    : 
Source                      : System.Management.Automation
```

Comment: It seems like you're trying to use $body like a reference or pointer.  That is you update $body after it has already been passed by value to the $email hashtable.  You need to update $email.Body after you update $body with the error

Comment: Thanks!  That seems to have done the trick... now if I could just figure out adding multiple attachments :P

Comment: For that you can just do Send-MailMessage -Attachments @('path/to/file1', 'path/to/file2')

Comment: I ended up with `Get-ChildItem -Path $intelDir | Where {$_.Name -match "$($(get-date -f MM-dd-yy))"} | foreach{$_.fullname} | Send-MailMessage @email`  Seriously last question, in looking at that code above, can you help me figure out why, if `$webclient.DownloadFile($url,$storageFile)` is passed an invalid (or offline) URL, the entire script stops processing?

Comment: does the script have an error? It could be because the webclient is trying to download the file synchronously.  So the script has to wait until the download completes but since the url is not valid the script waits until DownloadFile times out from no response

Comment: Hmmm, best way to explain it: If that sources.csv file has 3 entries and each throws an error, the `ForEach-Object` will process `catch` on all 3 and generate the appropriate log files, however, it will not proceed to `Send-MailMessage @email`

Comment: If it's logging at echo $intelerror then the try catch is working perfectly so it is probably something to do with what your passing into send-mailmessage.  Especially if it's trying to send an attachment that doesn't exist.

Comment: Updated with the new code as I realized enough had changed where you'd be helping me with at least one hand tied behind your back